# Binomial distribution where the number of experiments is binomially distributed

Tags: binomial-distribution, random-variable, covariance

In my setup,

- there are $m$ trials.
- Each trial has a probability $q$ of being selected.
- $N \leq m $ is the number of selected trials 
  $$ \rightarrow N \sim \text{Bin}(q, m) $$
- For each of the $N$ selected trials, the probability of success is $p$
- $K\leq N$ is the number of successful trials 
  $$ \rightarrow (K|N) \sim \text{Bin}(p, N) $$

I have already derived $E[K] = qmp $, and $Var(K)= qmp(1-p) + p^2 m q(1-q)$

However I am stuck in the derivation of *$cov(K, N)$*. I would appreciate any help to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [law of total covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance), 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(K,N)
  &=E\operatorname{Cov}(K,N|N)+\operatorname{Cov}(EK|N,EN|N)
\\&=E 0+\operatorname{Cov}(pN,N)
\\&=0+p\operatorname{Var}(N)
\\&=pmq(1-q).
\end{align}